# How to select a row with minimum value over some other column

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

How to select a rows from dataframe based on minimum value in one column aggregated over another column. For example

```
a = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'b': [10, 5, 10, 6, 5, 4, 5, 30, 25, 24, 30, 30], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
print(a)
-----------------
shape: (12, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 2   │
│ 1   ┆ 10  ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 6   ┆ 4   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 5   │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
│ 2   ┆ 5   ┆ 7   │
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 8   │
│ 3   ┆ 25  ┆ 9   │
│ 3   ┆ 24  ┆ 10  │
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 11  │
│ 3   ┆ 30  ┆ 12  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I need the following dataframe

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
│ 3   ┆ 24  ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

so it's like groupby(by='a'), them min('b'), but I need to select entire row with minimum b.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a `.filter` + `.over`

```
df.filter(pl.col('b') == pl.min('b').over('a'))
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 5   ┆ 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 4   ┆ 6   │
│ 3   ┆ 24  ┆ 10  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

To handle duplicates you could add `.unique(subset='a')`

It could also be written as a `.groupby`:

```
(df.groupby('a')
   .agg(
      pl.col('b', 'c').filter(pl.col('b') == pl.min('b')).first()
   )
)
```

Comment: This is good. But how to pick a single row, if there are multiple values of `b` equal to `min(b)`?

Comment: You could add a `.unique()`